# iOS UITabBar selectionIndicatorImage Y position

Tags: ios, swift

I have this spec:

[image]

But, i have this:

[image]

I have this code:

```
self.mTabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "footer-blue-line")
```

How can I set the Y position for the `selectionIndicatorImage`?

Comment: Just create an Image with hight of 44px, and set background transparent, make black lined portion at bottom, and set that image, it will create same effect as first image.

Comment: It seems this issue happens in iPhone X that the selection indicator image view has a vertical center constraint between the top of tab bar and the bottom of screen (out of the `safe area`), again. The right height solution doesn't work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you using a single "selected" image that has a blue line below it ?

Comment: Actually, i have only two image. I'm trying with it. If there is no solution, i'll use an another image

Answer (score 0):

http://s18.postimg.org/c5bjg501h/line.png

Use the image given on the link on the place of "footer-blue-line".

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You just need to set class of Tab Bar to this class in the interface builder

```
class MyCustomTabBar: UITabBar
{
    var didInit = false
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if didInit == false
        {
            didInit = true
            for subview in subviews {
                // can't hookup to subviews, so do layer.sublayers
                subview.layer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "sublayers", options: .New, context: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    deinit
    {
        for subview in subviews
        {
            subview.layer.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "sublayers")
        }
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
    {
        // layer.delegate is usually the parent view
        if let l = object as? CALayer, tbButton = l.delegate as? UIView where tbButton.window != nil
        {
            for v in tbButton.subviews
            {
                if String(v.dynamicType) == "UITabBarSelectionIndicatorView" {
                    v.setYOrigin(3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```